# Drop down menu - last item goes off screen

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

Trying to add right margin for the drop down item to the last menu item.

Here is the menu:
https://jsfiddle.net/5tymk7o4/11/

Here s what I'd like to get:

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
.dropdown-menu {
right: 0; 
 /* or */
margin-right: 0px;

}
```

both didn't work well

I have also tried to 
 1. add right margin to UL
 2. to make UL relative and add right: o to LI...

all in vain...

I swear I have searched for a good while before posting this question.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers, you can use right: 0 for that particular item.

To avoid targeting other menu items, use this selector:

```
#menue .menu-item:last-child .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: initial;
    margin-right: auto !important; /* Only if you can't delete the inline margin-right applied to this element */
}
```

This will apply the css only to the the dropdown menu inside the last menu item, leaving the alignment of the rest as is.

Comment: This is the better answer, so long as they still remove the margin-right inline style on that last menu item.

Comment: Thanks, @dukedevil294, I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! so damn easy and I have spent so much time on this (( Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Replace the inline margin-right: 1200px on the ul for the last menu item with:

```
left: auto; right: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add right: 0, left must be auto to work how you want

```
.dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```